# API gateway (Zuul) merging two micro service response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices, api-gateway

I have two micro service, user micro service and order micro service.

User micro service return's the user details and order micro service return the order details for the user.

http://localhost:8080/microservice1/getuser

{"id":"100","name":"test"}

http://localhost:8081/microservice2/getorders

{"userid":"100","orders":{"orderid":"5001","productname":"mobilephone"}}

I am using Spring cloud Zuul as API Gateway which is routing request to each micro service.

http://localhost:9090/api/microservice1/getuser

http://localhost:9090/api/microservice2/getorders

Now from UI, i need to call two endpoints

Is their any way to merge the response of both the micro service like
{"id":"100","name":"test","orders":{"orderid":"5001","productname":"mobilephone"}}

So that client only need to call one endpoint http://localhost:9090/api/getdetail

how we can achieve this at API Gateway level ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zuul should not be use to aggregate response , you can create orchestration microservice service and internally using restTemplate get all response and aggregate as per need.

Keep Zuul as stateless, gateway should not have any logic or stateful.

Comment: thanks @vaquar Khan,  In the third orchestration  micro service, how to send simultaneous request, can we use Reactive approach or traditional approach like send one request and wait for the another one

Comment: If you want to send consolidated response then should be synch call if you want to dump request or response into db or rabbit/kafka then use asynchronous call . Reactive is best if your infra supported.